# T-SQL select script with union

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

this is my scripts

```
Select @Mydate [Date], 'Normal DateTime' [Describe]
Select Convert(varchar,@Mydate,101) [Date],'Format 101' [Describe]
```

and result is:

```
  Date                            Describe
  2011-12-10 16:32:00.800         Normal DateTime

  Date                            Describe
  12/10/2011                      Format 101
```

but when I union this 2 scripts the result is different:

```
Select @Mydate [Date], 'Normal DateTime' [Describe]
Union
Select Convert(varchar,@Mydate,101) [Date],'Format 101' [Describe]


  Date                            Describe
  2011-12-10 16:32:00.800         Normal DateTime
  2011-12-10 00:00:00.000         Format 101
```

I think the SQL try to fix the number of characters in both raw, so how can I use union and get the previous results?

Comment: You are mixing column types in result. The result is a relation (a table) and in a table all rows must be for the same type. Then SQLServer is doing type casting. What is your desirable result: date? Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Mydate, 121) [Date], 'Normal DateTime' [Describe]
Union
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Mydate, 101) [Date],'Format 101' [Describe]
```

Gives me an output of:

```
Date                      Describe
2011-12-10 16:32:00.000   Normal DateTime
12/10/2011                Format 101
```

When you cast both values to `VARCHAR` explicitly, they'll show up correctly (I hope!)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like variable `@Mydate` is of DateTime type and  DateTime precedence is higher than Date precedence.

[T-SQL UNION (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx):

> When data types differ, the resulting data type is determined based on
>   the rules for data type precedence.

[Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence.

Answer (score 0):

In a union you have one type per column.

`Convert(varchar,@Mydate,101) [Date]` is being unioned with a column that's a datetime (@Mydate) so it's automatically cast or converted to a datetime.

So ask yourself this.

How is 2011-12-10 16:32:00.800 and 12/10/2011 going to the same type?

Answer: [make the first a varchar too but in the long dateime format using Convert(varchar, @myDate, 21)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
declare @Mydate datetime
set @Mydate = getdate()

Select Convert(varchar,@Mydate,21) , 'Normal DateTime' [Describe]
Union
Select Convert(varchar,@Mydate,101) [Date],'Format 101' [Describe]


Date                           Describe
------------------------------ ---------------
2011-12-11 02:45:44.660        Normal DateTime
12/11/2011                     Format 101
```

(2 row(s) affected)